# New dataframe which contais a certain value within each group

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe as below

```
User    eve Ses
a   123 1
a   123 2
a   123 3
a   123 4
a   123 5
a   123 6
a   456 1
a   456 2
a   456 3
a   456 4
a   456 5
a   456 14
a   456 7
a   456 8
a   456 9
a   456 10
a   888 1
a   888 2
a   888 3
a   888 4
a   888 5
a   888 5
a   888 7
a   888 8
b   123 1
b   123 2
b   123 3
b   123 4
b   123 5
b   123 6
b   456 1
b   456 2
b   456 3
b   456 4
b   456 5
b   456 9
b   456 7
b   456 8
b   456 9
b   456 10
b   888 1
b   888 2
b   888 3
b   888 4
b   888 5
b   888 6
b   888 7
b   888 8
```

I want to group by `User` & `eve` and get a new dataframe with all the groups that contains 6 or 14

When I use the code below

`df.groupby(['User','eve']).apply(lambda x: (x['Ses']==6).any()|(x['Ses']==14).any())`
I accurately get the groups which have either 6 or 14 as below

```
User  eve
a     123     True
      456     True
      888    False
b     123     True
      456    False
      888     True
dtype: bool
```

I am just not able to use this information to get the new dataframe which has the groups that are `True`.
The expected output is the new dataframe as below. Can anyone guide?

```
User    eve Ses
a   123 1
a   123 2
a   123 3
a   123 4
a   123 5
a   123 6
a   456 1
a   456 2
a   456 3
a   456 4
a   456 5
a   456 14
a   456 7
a   456 8
a   456 9
a   456 10
b   123 1
b   123 2
b   123 3
b   123 4
b   123 5
b   123 6
b   888 1
b   888 2
b   888 3
b   888 4
b   888 5
b   888 6
b   888 7
b   888 8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For improve performance is possible use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and [`GroupBy.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.any.html) with mask created [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) and helper column by [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
df = df[df.assign(m=df['Ses'].isin([6,14])).groupby(['User','eve'])['m'].transform('any')]
print (df)
   User  eve  Ses
0     a  123    1
1     a  123    2
2     a  123    3
3     a  123    4
4     a  123    5
5     a  123    6
6     a  456    1
7     a  456    2
8     a  456    3
9     a  456    4
10    a  456    5
11    a  456   14
12    a  456    7
13    a  456    8
14    a  456    9
15    a  456   10
24    b  123    1
25    b  123    2
26    b  123    3
27    b  123    4
28    b  123    5
29    b  123    6
40    b  888    1
41    b  888    2
42    b  888    3
43    b  888    4
44    b  888    5
45    b  888    6
46    b  888    7
47    b  888    8
```

Your solution should be changed with [`DataFrameGroupBy.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html), but if larger DataFrame or many groups solution is really slow:

```
df = df.groupby(['User','eve']).filter(lambda x: (x['Ses']==6).any()|(x['Ses']==14).any())
```